# How to working with shape (polygon) in different browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, shapes

I am doing the shape using css in my website.
It work well in chrome, but when open in mozilla, internet explorer, it can't function.

Anyone know how to fixed it?

Here is the fiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dm3qe27o/2/

```
<div class="index-main-wrapper">
    <div class="home-left-shape"></div>
    <div class="home-right-shape"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

.home-left-shape {
height:100vh;
width:50vw;
float:left;
background-color:#bfb6a5;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
-webkit-shape-margin: 20px;
}
.home-right-shape {
height:100vh;
width:50vw;
float:right;
background-color:#bfb6a5;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
shape-outside: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
-webkit-shape-margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: [`clip-path` is not supported in IE and only partially supported in Firefox using `url()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Comment: @misterManSam I see, if like this do you have any idea of other method or coding that can be use?

Answer (score 0):

use different browser

`-webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);` -mozila & chrom

```
-moz-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%); - mozila
```

`-o-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);` - opera

`-ms-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);` - Internet Exploler